# Tensorflow dependencies: tensorflow 1.15.0 has requirement tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0 : What's the solution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dependencies, dependency-management

I have this list of dependencies:

```
absl-py==0.7.0
bleach==1.5.0
click==6.7
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.2.1
futures==3.1.1
h5py==2.7.1
html5lib==0.9999999
imageio==2.2.0
Keras==2.1.5
Markdown==2.6.11
matplotlib==3.1.1
networkx==2.1
numpy==1.16.0
Pillow==5.0.0
pip-autoremove==0.9.0
protobuf==3.7
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.3
PyWavelets==0.5.2
PyYAML==3.12
scikit-image==0.13.1
scipy==1.1.0
six==1.12.0
tensorflow-gpu
tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1
tqdm==4.19.5
Werkzeug==0.15
```

I have these errors:

> ERROR: tensorflow 1.15.0 has requirement tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0, but you'll have tensorboard 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: tensorflow 1.15.0 has requirement tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1, but you'll have tensorflow-estimator 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: albumentations 0.1.12 has requirement imgaug<0.2.7,>=0.2.5, but you'll have imgaug 0.2.9 which is incompatible.

What's the solution? Should I use an external tool to solve this dependencies problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uninstall conflicting dependencies. For `tensorflow` it would be:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow tensorflow-tensorboard tensorflow-estimator
```

(maybe there are some more, not sure).

Secondly, reinstall `tensorflow` by issuing (change pinned version to whatever you want, maybe new `2.0`):

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
```

Same for other dependencies, uninstall what's necessary and install with explicit version pinning as displayed by your error.

Finally, appropriate `tensorboard` is downloaded when you install `tensorflow` (same for `estimator`) at least in Tensorflow `2.0`. If not, you may have to install those explicitly, same as your `tensorflow` version. Consult installed packages list if necessary.